# Need JSSOR Slider to land on specific image depending on referring page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jssor

Pretty new to Javascript and am working on a slider that needs to start with a specific image depending on which page the viewer came from.

I've worked a little directly with JSSOR but have come to the point where I can't get it to work.

There are a few points where I could be off in capturing the document referrer or in setting the image index.

Do you need to assign an index to each image in the slider for it to work or are they automatically indexed from top to bottom?

Here's the code for the first image in the slider - no index assigned

```
<div data-p="208.625">
    <img data-u="image" src="images/Seat_Gray_1.jpg" title="Gray seat option 1" alt="Gray seat, first option"/>
    <img data-u="thumb" src="images/Seat_Gray_1.jpg" width="150px"/>
</div>
```

Here's the code with the attempt to capture the referring page and set the first image depending on which page from the site it came from:

Here's the original slider code that it started with:

```
jssor_1_slider_init = function() {

        var jssor_1_options = {
          $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
          },
          $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,
            $Cols: 6,
            $SpacingX: 8,
            $SpacingY: 15,
            $Align: 395
          }
        };

        var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);
```

Now, inserting the new code to get the referring url to decide where the startIndex should be. The image page works, but always starts at the first slide (slide 0).

Is below the correct places to add the new code?

```
jssor_1_slider_init = function() {

/************************ Jump Test start ********************/
        var startIndex = 0;

        var incomingPage = document.referrer;

        if ( incomingPage == "http://www.example.com/black_seats.php" ) {
            startIndex: 4;

        } else if ( incomingPage == "http://www.example.com/red_products.php" ) {
            startIndex: 8;

        } else if ( incomingPage == "http://www.example.com/green_products.php" ) {
            startIndex: 14;

       } else {
           startIndex: 0;
       }

/************************ Jump Test end - start of original script ********************/

        var jssor_1_options = {
          $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
          },
          $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,
            $Cols: 6,
            $SpacingX: 8,
            $SpacingY: 15,
            $Align: 395
          }
        };

/************************ Jump Test add start index ********************/

        var jssor_slider_options = {
            $StartIndex: startIndex
  };

/************************ Final line of original code ********************/

        var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It initializes with `jssor_1_options`, but you set $StartIndex to `jssor_slider_options`.

Comment: Great! So I add the $StartIndex here:

    var jssor_1_options = {
          $StartIndex,
          $ArrowNavigatorOptions...

@jssor

Comment: Yeah, it should work then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it to work! Realizing that I needed multiple images from a single page to land on different images, I started looking at sending and capturing the variable from the PHP side. I added the variable string to each image link:

```
    <a href="seats.php?incomingCategory=blackSeat01">
    <img src="images/BlackSeat01_thumb.jpg" ...
    </a>
```

Then on the landing image slider page I added this PHP code before the slider initialization to capture the incoming variable:

```
    <?php
    $incomingCategory = $_GET['incomingCategory'];
    ?>
```

Once that is sent, in the slider function, I added the following if/else statement to echo the incoming string variable and direct the slider to the correct slide:

```
    var startIndex = 0;

    //put php variable to a javascript variable 
    var incomingPage = <?php echo json_encode($incomingCategory, JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>; 

        if ( incomingPage == "graySeat01" ) {
            startIndex = 0;

        } 

        else if ( incomingPage == "blackSeat01" ) {
            startIndex = 3;

        }

        else if ( incomingPage == "blackSeat02" ) {
            startIndex = 4;

        }

        else if ( incomingPage == "blueSeat01" ) {
            startIndex = 8;

        }

        else if ( incomingPage == "blueSeat02" ) {
            startIndex = 9;

        }

        else {
            startIndex = 0;
        }
```

Now it's working perfectly every time. I was having issues with it working early on as I had the variable set to the string with a single =. The string was getting captured, but it wasn't changing the slide. Changed it to == and voila!

Thank you @jssor for the help with this - cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
//specifies startIndex according to page comes from
var startIndex = 0;

var jssor_1_options = {
  $StartIndex: startIndex,
  $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
    $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
  },
  $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
    $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,
    $Cols: 6,
    $SpacingX: 8,
    $SpacingY: 15,
    $Align: 395
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks @jssor, I created a new page with the fresh slider. However, I added  $StartIndex: startIndex,  to the options and now the entire slider disappears from the page... I haven't even added the if else statement, just adding the option for $StartIndex seems to have made it go away.

Comment: please replace your `$StartIndex,` with `$StartIndex: startIndex,`

Comment: That is what I did, the entire script looks like this now - only adding that line in the options makes the slider disappear

`jssor_1_slider_init = function() {

            var jssor_1_options = {
     $StartIndex: startIndex, //added start index option
              $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
              },
`

@jssor

Comment: I see, please leave an url of your page here.

Comment: Thanks @jssor - I sent an e-mail to jssor_dev with the urls and details. I did figure out why it disappeared - when I added `var startIndex = 0;` then the slider works again. I added the if statement as well, but both referring pages still land on image #1 - not the images specified. Thanks again

Comment: Please write log to check if the startIndex is correct. `console.log("startIndex: " + startIindex)`

Comment: Thank you @jssor - of course copy/paste put curly quotes around the console.log string... anyway - it's somwehat working now - I sent another e-mail with the updated links and details - basically it's capturing the referrer the first time and directing to the correct image, but subsequent clicks from the other links don't change it - it still logs as clicked in from the first referrer...

Comment: any other help you can offer on this? Did you get the updated pages via e-mail last week? Thanks

Comment: Still working on this @jssor - does anyone know how this can be done? Perhaps there is an easier way to get the slider to start on a specific image depending on which page it came from?

Comment: See the updated answer, please specify `startIndex` before initialize jssor slider.

Comment: Thanks @jssor - where do I add the function that points to the corresponding image. I sent an e-mail with our updated code.